# Wx Python : Status Bar Does Not Show Menu Messages

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I am just starting out with wx python and I can't get the status bar to display help text from menu items.I read that statusbar messages can be set with `SetStatusText()` but I want help texts like this to be displayed. I am using Ubuntu 14.04/wxPython 2.8/Python 2.7.6. Please help. Thanks in advance.

```
import wx

class Test(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent,id):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent,id,"Frame aka Window",size = (300,200))
        panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.status=self.CreateStatusBar()
        #self.status.SetStatusText("Something")
        menubar=wx.MenuBar()

        first=wx.Menu()
        second=wx.Menu()

        first.Append(wx.NewId(),"New Window","This is a new window")
        first.Append(wx.NewId(),"Open...","Open A New Window")
        menubar.Append(first,"File")
        menubar.Append(second,"Edit")        
        self.SetMenuBar(menubar)



if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame=Test(None,id=-1)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: In wxPython 2.9 (and all other versions, I guess) the third argument in `menu.Append(…, …, 'helptext')` gets displayed in the status bar when hovering over the menu item automagically. Did you add the menu to a `wx.MenuBar` instance? Did you set the menu bar? Did you `self.CreateStatusBar()` on the frame? Or did you want to achieve something else?

Comment: I did all of these. I just want to display the help text.

Comment: Yes? And what happens in the status bar when you hover over a `Menu` entry? `MenuBar` entries do not seem to have help texts. If in your **minimal working** example the help texts do not show up when hovering, post the entire code in your question.

Comment: But I have specified help messages in the code. Why doesn't help messages show up then???

Comment: Mhhh... Your example works for me on Win7/wxPython 2.9/python 2.7.6 32 bit (as mentioned, only on menu entries, not the top level menu enties File and Edit. What are your specs?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04/wxPython2.8/Python2.7.6. I meant to have it in menu entries.

Comment: Ok, then we should wait for someone familiar with that platform. Also update your question with this information.

Comment: @nepix32 I am also experiencing problems with other methods such as `SetBackgroundColour()` and so I am going to switch to another GUI builder. wxPython is EXTREMELY buggy it seems.

Comment: I am very sad to hear that. Over the years I have found wxPython to be a very reliable, low-footprint GUI toolkit. I was very amazed when projects developed on Windows did run with almost no changes at all on Ubuntu 12.04 and a common codebase is completely feasible. What I hated very much is that the recommended way of installing packages like wxPython by the distro packet manager, which only has quite old aka "stable" versions (you can run in trouble compiling dependencies if you want to go from scratch). You can try if you find a package for wx 2.9 or even 3.0. But this is another story.

Comment: This code works for me on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, wxPython 2.8.12.1 with Python 2.7.6. wxPython is not very buggy. You have to realize that wxPython uses the actual widgets whenever possible. This means that on some platforms you cannot set the background color of widgets because the native widget on that platform does not support it.

Comment: Try `app = wx.App()`. PySimpleApp is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Your code worked fine on my windows8 with wxpython 3.0. Try this code:

```
import wx
class Test( wx.Frame ):

    def __init__( self, parent ):
        wx.Frame.__init__ ( self, parent, id = wx.ID_ANY, title = "Frame aka Window", pos = wx.DefaultPosition, size = wx.Size( 300,200 ), style = wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE )

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self.status = self.CreateStatusBar( 1, 0, wx.ID_ANY )

        self.menu = wx.MenuBar( 0 )
        self.first = wx.Menu()
        self.new = wx.MenuItem( self.first, wx.ID_ANY, "New Window", u"This is a new window", wx.ITEM_NORMAL )
        self.first.AppendItem( self.new )
        self.open = wx.MenuItem( self.first, wx.ID_ANY, "Open", u"Open a new window", wx.ITEM_NORMAL )
        self.first.AppendItem( self.open )
        self.menu.Append( self.first, "File" ) 
        self.second = wx.Menu()
        self.menu.Append( self.second, "Menu" ) 
        self.SetMenuBar( self.menu )
        self.Centre( wx.BOTH )



if __name__=='__main__':
    app=wx.App()
    frame=Test(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```